# Full page Screenshot with mechanize in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize

I have a page and I want to take a full page screenshot. We have a function in capybara/poltergeist with save_screenshot. Is there anything like this in mechanize?

Answer (score 1):

So I guess I figured it out..

I used https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit gem which converts html to image.

kit = IMGKit.new(page.body)
file = kit.to_file('path to your file/image.png')